# Is Data's leg length of eighty-seven point two centimetres based on an actual measurement?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-insurrection

From Star Trek: Insurrection:

> DATA: My legs are exactly eighty-seven point two centimetres in length. They were eighty-seven point two centimetres the day I was created. They will be eighty-seven point two centimetres the day I go off line.

I'm curious if anyone involved in production of the movie, including Spiner himself, has ever commented on if an actual leg measurement of Spiner was used to derive this number.

Or was it just a reasonable sounding number they made up for the movie?

Comment: Brent Spiner's legs probably aren't both the same length to the nearest 0.1 cm, and either leg is probably not the same length in the morning as it is in the evening, if you're measuring to the nearest 0.1 cm.

Comment: Agreed. But that doesn't preclude that they used an actual measurement, at some point in time, for the script. I tried to make the question more clear to reflect that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The measurement is pretty much spot-on, depending on how you measure the length of a leg. Taking this picture as our benchmark

[image]

and with the info (from various [sources](https://www.celebheights.com/s/Brent-Spiner-2733.html)) that Brent Spiner is 5'10'' tall (177cm) we can guesstimate his inside leg as being approx 70cm and his total leg measurement (from the widest part of his hip to his ankle) as **89.5cm**, give or take a few centimeters.

[image]

I would imagine that the writers would have ready access to his measurements from the production team's uniform designers.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the costume designers - great catch. I'd still love an actual quote from production if one exists but otherwise I think this is an acceptable answer.